# Understanding a sum in the Bravais lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

In our solid-state physics course one frequently uses the identity

$$ \sum\limits_{\vec{R}}e^{i\vec{R}(\vec{k} - \vec{k}')} = N\delta_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'} $$
where the summation goes over the Bravais lattice and $N$ is the number of primitive unit cells. However, I don't understand why $ \sum\limits_{\vec{R}}e^{i\vec{R}(\vec{k} - \vec{k}')}$ apparently vanishes for $\vec{k} \ne \vec{k}'$ and could not find a proof.

Why is this? Do I need a further assumptions like the Born-von Karman boundary condition to derive this? I am struggling because it seems $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{k'}$ can in principle be real in which case I cannot use the sum of the nth roots of unity...

Answer (score 6):

It's just a generalisation of the discrete Fourier transform in higher dimensions. You have for $N$ a positive integer and $m$ integers modulo $N$:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{i2\pi mn/N} = N\delta_m
$$
with $\delta$ here the discrete Dirac delta function:
$$
\delta_m = \begin{cases}
1 & m\equiv 0\, [N] \\ 0 & m\not \equiv 0\, [N]
\end{cases}
$$
If you have a finite $D$ dimensional lattice with periodic boundary conditions of sides $N_1... N_D$, the lattice (the set of sites) is therefore:
$$
\Lambda = \mathbb Z/N_1\mathbb Z \times ...\times \mathbb Z/N_D\mathbb Z
$$
Due to the finite real domain, the the wave vectors are discretised and lie in the dual lattice:
$$
\Lambda^*=\{(2\pi n_1/N_1,...,2\pi n_D/N_D)|(n_1,...,n_D)\in \Lambda\}
$$
Note that there are as many sites as wave vectors, namely $N = N_1...N_D$.

Now your result is obtained by multiplying the first formula $D$ times. For $k\in\Lambda^*$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{x\in\Lambda}e^{ik\cdot x} &= \prod_{i=1}^D\sum_{n_i=0}^{N_i-1}e^{ik_in_i}\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^D N_i\delta_{k_i} \\
&= N\delta_k
\end{align}
$$
with the multidimensional discrete Dirac delta:
$$
\delta_m = \begin{cases}
1 & \frac{N_1k_1}{2\pi}\equiv 0\, [N_1], \, ...\, \frac{N_Dk_D}{2\pi}\equiv 0\, [N_D]\\ 0
\end{cases}
$$
As the domain size goes to infinity, the wave vectors belong in a continuous set. The formula becomes in the continuum limit:
$$
\sum_{x\in\Lambda}e^{ik\cdot x} = V^*\delta(k)
$$
if $k,k'$ are in the same Brillouin zone, or considered modulo $\Lambda^*$. $V^*$ the volume of the fundamental domain to the lattice $\Lambda^*$ (the Brillouin zone). In full generality, it is:
$$
\sum_{x\in\Lambda}e^{ik\cdot x} = V^*\sum_{l\in\Lambda^*}\delta(k-l)
$$
This is the Poisson summation formula in higher dimensions.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1. A comment, which might help to see the connection (through the thermodynamic limit) between your first (or better the one with $\delta_k$) and last equation better: Your $\delta_m$ can be written as $\delta_m=\sum\limits_{z\in \mathbb Z}\delta_{m,\mathbb ZN}$, where the $\delta$ on the RHS is the usual Kronecker delta. And the very first equation in turn can be proven from the partial sums of the geometric series.